# Kotlin is there a map function for nullable values

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I want to map a nullable value, apply a function inside the value if exists, if not return null.

Comment: Just use ?.[let](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html), as in `nullableValue?.let { it.foo() }`

Comment: Yes... ?.let does the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I end up creating an extension function:

```
fun <A, B> A?.mapNullable(f: (A) -> B): B? = if (this == null) null else f(this)
```

and you can use it like

```
nullValue.mapNullable { it.something }
```

Finally this is exactly the same to do `nullValue?.let {...}`

Comment: The term “map” implies a many-to-many relationship. I would just use the built-in `let` function since it’s idiomatic for the language. Makes it easier for others to immediately understand your code at a glance.